# Create nginx "sites-available" and "site-enabled" files along content using terminal commands

Tags: linux, terminal, digital-ocean, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have been assigned a task to automate the deployment process using digital ocean droplets. I am using doctl for creating the subdomain "A" record from my terminal using doctl commands. After creating subdomain "A" records I have to create a configuration file in the sites-available and sites-enabled folder with the same name as a subdomain "A" record. Can someone help me with how to create these files along with their configuration content inside using terminal commands?

Answer (score 0):

Just moved to the directory (/etc/nginx/sites-available) and use the cat command following by the filename. Detail [Here](https://linuxize.com/post/create-a-file-in-linux/#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20new%20file%20run%20the%20cat%20command%20followed,D%20to%20save%20the%20files.)

```
cat << EOF > filename
line no 1 
line no 2 
line no 3 
EOF
```